# Pass result from WaterfallDialog's stepContext to DialogContext

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using Microsoft Bot v4 Framework. I have a ComponentDialog that invokes a WaterfallDialog.

```
public class MainDialog : ComponentDialog 
{
   public MainDialog() 
   {
       var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
       {
          DoSomething,
       }
       AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog("wfDialog", waterfallSteps));
   }

   private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DoSomething(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken tkn)
   {
       var someresult = "This is the result to be sent back";
       return dc.EndDialogAsync(someresult);
   }
   
    public override async Task 
         EndDialogAsync (ITurnContext tc, DialogInstance d, DialogReason r, CancellationToken tkn)
    {
        // I need that result in this method. I experimented all options.
        // Last option is Saving it via state accessors. But is it the only option ?
    }
}
```

Seeking your assistance to pass the Result from WaterfallStepContext to DialogContext.

Thanks,
pdeeepa

Comment: If you need 'someresult' within the same turn, you could consider using turnState.

Comment: is your issue resolved?